# two button same line in windows phone

Tags: wpf, stackpanel

This is the first time I've coded with WPF. I have 1 StackPanel, and in it 2 Buttons. But, when i try order two buttons on the same line, I can't.

Here is my configuration:

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,0,0,45">
    <StackPanel.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Resources/layer-top.png"/>
    </StackPanel.Background>

    <Button  Margin="0,0,0,0"  Width="80" HorizontalAlignment="Left" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Height="75" BorderThickness="3">
        <Button.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Resources/button-menu.png"/>
        </Button.Background>
    </Button>

    <Button Content="All" Foreground="#FFCFCF10" Margin="200,0,134,0" BorderBrush="{x:Null}">
        <Button.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Resources/button_all.png"/>
        </Button.Background>
    </Button>

    <TextBlock Text="GoodStories" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

How do I get the two Buttons to appear on the same line?

Comment: Try setting `Orientation="Horizontal"` on your `StackPanel`.

Comment: ok. it's ok, but now two button can't near together. help me pro

Comment: Something with margins? May I suggest reading a WPF book or tutorial?

Comment: margins, padding, why i don't know it ?. hihi, ok tks sir, I solved it